# Unable to instantiate SparkSession

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, admin

I try to configure hadoop cluster with spark and hive.

I use Hadoop 3.1.3 version with Hive 3.1.3 and prebuild Spark 3.0.0 with user-provided hadoop.

When I deploy all, I shouldn't connect to hive metastore from spark. So, I try this and get following

```
./bin/run-example sql.hive.SparkHiveExample
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.enableHiveSupport(SparkSession.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive.SparkHiveExample$.main(SparkHiveExample.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.sql.hive.SparkHiveExample.main(SparkHiveExample.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
20/07/06 15:26:27 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/07/06 15:26:28 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-246ae724-072f-45b1-9c89-cf122203a3df
```

I set classpath like [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html)

What I should do for a successful link spark and hive?

Comment: How I can add hive jars in class path?? I tried to define it using --jars option. I use hadoop from hadoop.apache.org/releases.html

Comment: I export CLASSPATH variable as /home/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib

Comment: I am not sure your hadoop installation processes.. try check - https://tech.marksblogg.com/hadoop-3-single-node-install-guide.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer:) I hope it should be useful for me

Comment: Add more details in your question how you installed hadoop cluster.. so that any one from hadoop admin can help you.. this is more related to admin part & also tag your question admin or hadoop admin ..

Comment: I solved my problem using another version of spark. Originally I tried to use spark-3.0.0-without-hadoop, but it was better to use spark-3.0.0 with hadoop 3.2. If someone knows how to deploy spark without hadoop please write here.